# Как правильно установить  кодировку  файла php ?

Tags: кодировка, php

При пересылке сообщения со страницы сайта в файле php `$result=mail("xxx@mail.ru", "Вам пришло письмо"," Имя : $_POST[name]`, cообщение `$_POST[commеnts]` идут ошибки  кодировки.

Кодировка всего файла в формате  Utf-8 не  срабатывает у  меня!

Comment: Возможно здесь уже нашла ответ: 

 $rem_mail = '[e-mail]';
    mail($rem_mail, "Проверка", "Это тестовое письмо", "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");

Answer (score 3):

То что у вас файлик в utf-8 почту это никаким боком не волнует. "Скажите" ей про это сами в дополнительных хиадерах.

```
mail ("xxx@mail.ru", "Вам пришло письмо"," Имя : $_POST[name], cообщение$_POST[commеnts]", "Content-Type: text/plain; charset='UTF-8'");
```

Comment: Работает код :mail ("xxx@YA.ru", "Вам пришло письмо"," Имя : $_POST[name], cообщение$_POST[commеnts]", "Content-Type: text/plain; charset='UTF-8'");  == для xxx@YA.RU
А на почте  mail.ru  само письмо не читаемо ??!

Answer (score 0):

Так-же с русскими буквами желательно не забывать про subject, лучше всего покодировать в QP или Base64. Пример с base64:

```
mail ( "xxx@mail.ru", "=?utf-8?b?" . base64_encode("Проверка") . "?=", "Это тестовое письмо", "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Или использовать уже готовые функции, см. http://php.net/mb_encode_mimeheader

Answer (score 0):

Могу порекомендовать библиотеку http://webi.ru/webi_files/php_libmail.html, легкая, удобная, с русскими комментами